# HTTPS request/response in Android

Tags: android, https

Need to send a POST request to a Service provider using HTTPS protocol, response from the service provider will be an xml file, need to read that also.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by taking a look at [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) and at [HttpPost](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html).

Something like this *should* work:

```
 final AndroidHttpClient httpClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
 HttpResponse httpresponse   = null;
 HttpEntity httpentity       = null;
 HttpUriRequest httprequest = new HttpPost("https://...");
 byte[] xmlByteArray = null;

 if ((httpresponse = httpClient.execute(httprequest)) != null) {
  if ((httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity()) != null) {
   xmlByteArray = EntityUtils.toByteArray(httpentity);
  }
 }
```

Also, my [RestClient](http://github.com/aprock/ShortcutLink/blob/master/src/org/bibimbap/shortcutlink/RestClient.java) on github might be useful.
Note: I use GET to retrieve the data, so YMMV.

Comment: you did not answer the implied question.