# HTTPS requests: SchemeRegistry necessary?

Tags: android, https, request, httpclient

Basing on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603691/android-httpclient-and-https) (April 2010) they said that it is necessary to configure the HttpClient with a proper SchemeRegistry in order to send HTTPS requests.

[This other response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989806/https-request-response-in-android) (October 2010), instead, says it is sufficient to specify HTTPS protocol in the request uri.

I tried to perform HTTPS requests simply adding "https" in the uri address and it seems to work (I tried with address like www.google.com or www.facebook.com). Does something changed in the standard library between April and October 2010? Or there're specific cases in which I must use a solution rather than another?

Thanks.